# OBJ-C wipe NSData content before nullifying it

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdata, memset

For security reasons we need Always to wipe sensitive data from memory.
Usually it is not something that i see done in IOS but for apps and need extended security it is very important.

The Data that Usually needs to be wiped if NSData and NSString objects (pointing to nil does not wipe the data and it is a security breach)

I've managed to wipe my NSStrings with the code below (When password is NSString):

```
unsigned char *charPass;
if (password != nil) {
    charPass = (unsigned char*) CFStringGetCStringPtr((CFStringRef) password, CFStringGetSystemEncoding());
    memset(charPass, 0, [password length]);
    password = nil;
}
```

- Big remark on this implementation: You HAVE to check for NULL before calling the charPass or it might crash. There is NO guarantee that CFStringGetCStringPtr will return a value!

When password is NSData It suppose to be even more strait forward and the code bellow suppose to work:

```
memset([password bytes], 0, [password length]);
```

But this gives me a compilation error:

> No matching function for call to 'memset'

I can't find a workaround to point to the password address and wipe the bytes over there like I did with the string (bytes method should let me do just that from what I understand but it doesn't compile for some reason that I cant figure out)

Any one has an idea for this?

10x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I cannot speak for the actual safety of doing this, your problem is that `NSData`'s `bytes` method returns a `const void *`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1410616-bytes?language=objc

You can cast it to a `void *` if you want by

```
memset((void *)[password bytes], 0, [password length]);
```

If you use a `NSMutableData`, you won't have to do this.

Comment: Hi @Mobile Ben, Just figure it out myself and then saw you answer.... 10x

Answer (score 2):

Your string deallocator is *fragile*. You write:

> Big remark on this implementation: You HAVE to check for NULL before calling the charPass or it might crash. There is NO guarantee that CFStringGetCStringPtr will return a value!

This is documented behaviour as `CFString` (and hence `NSString`) does **not** guarantee you direct access to its internal buffer. You don't say what how you handle this situation, but if you don't erase the memory you presumably have a security problem.

In the case you do get a valid pointer back you are using the wrong byte count. The call `[password length]` returns:

> The number of UTF-16 code units in the receiver.

which is not the same as the number of bytes. However `CFStringGetCStringPtr` returns:

> A pointer to a C string or NULL if the internal storage of theString does not allow this to be returned efficiently.

If you have a C string you can use C library function `strlen()` to find its length.

To address the case when `CFStringGetCStringPtr` returns `NULL` you could create the string yourself as a `CFString` and supply a custom `CFAllocater`. You shouldn't need to write a complete allocator yourself, instead you could build one based on the system one. You can get the default allocators `CFAllocatorContext` which will return you the function pointers the system uses. You can then create a new `CFAllocator` based of a `CFAllocatorContext` which is a copy of the default one except you've changed the `deallocate` and `reallocate` pointers to functions which you have implemented in terms of the default `allocate`, `reallocate` and `deallocate` but also call `memset` appropriately to clear out memory.

Once you've done that doing your security wipe comes down to making sure these custom created `CFString` objects, aka `NSString` objects, are deallocated before your app quits.

You can find out about `CFAllocator`, `CFAllocatorContext` etc. in [Memory Management Programming Guide for Core Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/CFMemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000127-SW1).

Which brings us to your actual question, how to zero an `NSData`. Here you are in luck an `NSData` object is a `CFData` object, and `CFData`'s `CFDataGetBytePtr`, unlike `CFStringGetCStringPtr`, is guaranteed to return a pointer to the actual bytes, straight from the documentation:

> This function is guaranteed to return a pointer to a `CFData` object's internal bytes. `CFData`, unlike `CFString`, does not hide its internal storage.

So code following your pattern for `CFString` will work here. Note that using `NSData`'s `bytes` is **not** guaranteed in the documentation to call `CFDataGetBytePtr`, it could for example call `CFDataGetBytes` and return a *copy* of the bytes, use the `CFData` functions.

HTH

Comment: Hi @CRD, You are right and what i did eventually is to create same methods with deferent signatures with NSMutableData instead, That way i don't break the existing API and if anyone needs the extra security they will use the more secured methods that in them I can wipe the memory with memset method. There is not real way to wipe NSStrings bytes from memory from what i understand. 10x.